# how to access my lan based postgresql db from my website

Tags: c#, php, .net, postgresql, lan

We have lan based .Net application with Postgresql 8.1 , now i have task to provide interface on website to read and write two tables on LAN based database I don't know where to start Please help me to solve this problem.

Lan: Windows NT 2003
.Net 
Postgresql 8.1

Website:
PHP 5.3
Mysql

Comment: @MarcB how about making the link a bit more specific to the issue at hand yes?

Comment: You should also consider upgrading to a supported PostgreSQL version as soon as possible. 8.1 is definitely dead. 8.2 is the oldest version still being maintained but will be dropped at the end of this year. Additionally there were major performance improvements since then as well. I highly recommed to go straight for 9.1

Comment: If you're already in production, I'd hold off on 9.1 until it's been out for 6 months or so.  9.0 has been out over a year and is rock solid stable.  There's still the occasional wtf moment on the lists with 9.1

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable remote connections on Postgres. But be wary of security implications.

Haven't read it all, but [this](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/postgres-allow-remote-access-tcp-connection.html) should give you an idea on the steps to take on the server. For the connector, you generally just need to point the connect function at the remote IP.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to do the trick. Copied from [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pgsql.examples-basic.php):

```
 <?php
// Connecting, selecting database
$dbconn = pg_connect("host=localhost dbname=publishing user=www password=foo")
    or die('Could not connect: ' . pg_last_error());

// Performing SQL query
$query = 'SELECT * FROM authors';
$result = pg_query($query) or die('Query failed: ' . pg_last_error());

// Printing results in HTML
echo "<table>\n";
while ($line = pg_fetch_array($result, null, PGSQL_ASSOC)) {
    echo "\t<tr>\n";
    foreach ($line as $col_value) {
        echo "\t\t<td>$col_value</td>\n";
    }
    echo "\t</tr>\n";
}
echo "</table>\n";

// Free resultset
pg_free_result($result);

// Closing connection
pg_close($dbconn);
?>
```

in the above code, replace **localhost** by the **IP-address of your Postgres host**.

Answer (score 0):

On Linux, two files need to be modified to allow connections other than from localhost: 
postgresql.conf, change the listen_addresses = "*" to accept connections from anywhere.  Then add a line to the pg_hba.conf file to allow access to the database from a particular IP or network.  If you are not worried about security, entering:

host  all  all 192.168.1.0/24 trust

will allow anyone on the 192.168.1.0/24 network access to any database.  Obviously this should only be used to test you can reach the database.  Constrain this to the web servers IP address and use md5 so encrypted password authentication is used.